# What is the established antonym for "confluent"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice, is-it-a-word

I am not sure if I can use "[diffluent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/diffluent)" as it sounds incorrect to me even though it has a dictionary reference.

---

**Edit:**
Is the following sentence correct?

> Consecutive droughts led to the *diffluence* of natives to other regions in search of greener pastures.

Comment: @JEL - I have edited and included an example in my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example indicates that 'diaspora' might be the appropriate word:

> **diaspora**, *n.*
>   2. In extended use. Any group of people who have spread or become dispersed beyond their traditional homeland or point of origin; the dispersion or spread of a group of people in this way; an instance of this. Also: the countries and places inhabited by such a group, regarded collectively.
>   ....
>   3. The state or fact of having been dispersed from one's homeland or point of origin.

In your example, 'diaspora' fits:

> Consecutive droughts led to the diaspora of natives to other regions in search of greener pastures.

I suppose you could stretch the point, but in your example sentence, *diffluence* seems wrong to me. This is because *diffluence* refers to 'dispersal by flowing'. While you could say figuratively that the natives are *flowing* to other areas, it seems to be an unnecessary and possibly awkward figurative reach when more apt terms exist.

If you want a less ponderous (and more general) word, 'dispersal' or 'dispersion' would also work:

> **dispersion**, *n.*
>   1. The action of dispersing or scattering abroad; the condition or state of being dispersed; scattering, distribution, circulation.

(All definitions from [*OED Online*](http://oed.com/).)

So, thus in your example:

> Consecutive droughts led to the dispersal of natives to other regions in search of greener pastures.

Answer (score 4):

[Diffluent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Diffluent) is a less common term  compared to *confluent*, but it is used especially in scientific/formal contexts:

> - Flowing apart or off; dissolving; not fixed. (TFD)

Usage Example:

> - Confluent and/or [diffluent](https://books.google.it/books?id=gobh8VMiobYC&pg=PA93&dq=%22diffluent%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkouaN2dDJAhVFrxoKHa7PAKAQ6AEIVzAI#v=onepage&q=%22diffluent%22&f=false) wind patterns were observed in echo bands in all quadrants and at different elevations in the area around the radar.  (Cloud Dynamics: Proceedings of a Symposium held at the Third ...)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=diffluent&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiffluent%3B%2Cc0): *diffluent*.

As per your update I'd suggest ***migration***:

> - Movement of people to a new area or country in order to find work or better living conditions:
>     *the extensive rural-to-urban migration has created a severe housing shortage*

(ODO)

If you want to stick to a 'water' metaphor you can use ***outflow***:

> - anything that flows out, such as liquid, money, ideas, etc

Comment: I infer it is not wrong to use *diffluent*, only less common. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the term is corect , you can see other usage examples in the Ngram attached.

Answer (score 2):

In many contexts, ***divergent*** is the best antonym for *confluent*.

Quoting the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/38916?rskey=lvnTJ0&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) definitions:

> Confluent, *adj.* […]
>
> **1a.** Of streams or moving fluids: Flowing together so as to form one stream; uniting so as to form one body of fluid. […]
>
> **1b.** Also said of roads, valleys, mountain-chains, etc., and fig. of trains of circumstances.

> Divergent, *adj.* […]
>
> **1.** Proceeding in different directions from each other or from a common point; departing more widely from each other; diverging.

(In your particular example, though, I agree with other answers that *dispersal* or *diaspora* is better than *divergence*.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***branching out***

*Consecutive droughts led to the branching out of natives to other regions in search of greener pastures*.

> branch
>
> *n.*
>
> a. A tributary of a river.
>
> b. *Chiefly Southern US* creek. [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/branch)
>
> *v.*
>
> To separate into branches or branchlike parts. Also used with *out*
>   [The American Heritage® Roget's Thesaurus](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/branch)
>
> *The five women lived in and around Williamsburg and later branched out to other regions of Virginia.* [Cascaded Spirits](https://books.google.fr/books?id=0UmV59d-7gwC&pg=PT175&lpg=PT175&dq=%22branched+out+to+other+regions%22&source=bl&ots=DqHQ7tlSZ6&sig=uTi7f_cmWJubXHPZ4svQK7jouUk&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU05XMjNHJAhUB6RQKHcKZCpoQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22branched%20out%20to%20other%20regions%22&f=false)